# on save compile and deploy with maven eclipse and weblogic

Tags: eclipse, weblogic, maven, m2eclipse, weblogic-10.x

I just started maven in general and m2eclipse in specific.
What I have been doing before is follow:

1)Deploy my application to tomcat.
2) make any changes to the java or jsp files.
3) save and run the application again ( no restart is neccessary unless I changed a config file).

now, everytime I make a minor change to my maven project in eclipse I have to do a "pre-clean install" to compile and deploy the application again and then restart weblogic 10 to view the changes.

Is there anyway ( or maybe I m not doing something right) that I when I modify a class or jsp file, the code will get compiled and deployed when I save the file like I was doing before with the eclipse default project builder and tomcat?

Also, When I checkout the maven project from SVN, Eclipes shows bunch of compiling errors due to some missing classes, but when I build the project using m2eclipse everything builds successfull. Why is eclipse not recognizing the classes??

I have looked at the following answer but I was not able to figure out the problem.

[How do I start Maven "compile" goal on save in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632425/howto-start-maven-compile-goal-on-save-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> now, everytime I make a minor change to my maven project in eclipse I have to do a "pre-clean install" to compile and deploy the application again and then restart weblogic 10 to view the changes.

You shouldn't have to do that. Are you using the [Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (OEPE)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-1116-161753.html) (available from [the market place](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/oepe) or from [an update site](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15315_06/help/oracle.eclipse.tools.common.doc/html/install.html)) and the WTP?

> Is there anyway ( or maybe I m not doing something right) that I when I modify a class or jsp file, the code will get compiled and deployed when I save the file like I was doing before with the eclipse default project builder and tomcat?

See above.

> Also, When I checkout the maven project from SVN, Eclipes shows bunch of compiling errors due to some missing classes, but when I build the project using m2eclipse everything builds successful. Why is eclipse not recognizing the classes??

Try the following: **right-click** on the project then **Maven > Update Project Configuration**.