# eclipse do not run annotation processor(generate source file) automatically

Tags: java, eclipse

I have searched some questions by https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=annotation+processor+eclipse but none helped.

The one closest is [How to run annotation processor in eclipse on save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869771/how-to-run-annotation-processor-in-eclipse-on-save) but no final solution and the author switched to netbeans.

The file only generated by running maven command, refresh and clean project has no effect.

The project is :
https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-field-mapping
And I add `<m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>` to properties.

Here are some settings:
[image]

[image]

.factory:

```xml
<factorypath>
    <factorypathentry kind="VARJAR" id="M2_REPO/org/mapstruct/mapstruct/1.3.0.Beta2/mapstruct-1.3.0.Beta2.jar" enabled="true" runInBatchMode="false"/>
    <factorypathentry kind="VARJAR" id="M2_REPO/org/mapstruct/mapstruct-processor/1.3.0.Beta2/mapstruct-processor-1.3.0.Beta2.jar" enabled="true" runInBatchMode="false"/>
    <factorypathentry kind="VARJAR" id="M2_REPO/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.4/lombok-1.18.4.jar" enabled="true" runInBatchMode="false"/>
    <factorypathentry kind="PLUGIN" id="net.harawata.mybatipse" enabled="true" runInBatchMode="false"/>
    <factorypathentry kind="PLUGIN" id="org.eclipse.jst.ws.annotations.core" enabled="true" runInBatchMode="false"/>
</factorypath>
```

maven/annotation processing:

[image]

Other functions work well, eclipse knows the generated file and compile it, other java code can use these object as well.
Does eclipse just not support generate source file I guess...

Comment: The things that are done automatically when saving are done by so-called project builder. Have a look into the documentation/help and you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah..so I installed m2e-apt and post pictures with all configuration ready.But it still doesn't work...That's why I asked here... @howlger Could you please post url about the config I missed? I have already read official doc and search many times.

Comment: Sorry, the issue is unclear to me.