# Eclipse | Build Automatically for specific project currently open in workspace

Tags: eclipse, build

There are similar threads going on already but none talks about this specific question. Please don't flag this as **possible duplicate**.

I have got multiple projects imported in my eclipse workspace. 
Lets say I have:

- p1
- p2
- p3
- p4

The option "Build Automatically" is also enabled. Now the problem I'm facing is that if I'm working on **p1** and save any java file it builds all projects (that take a lot of time). I need other projects to keep open as I'm referring to those projects.

Now what I want is to build only the project in which I'm working; not all. Is there any possible configuration available? Also I don't want to disable "Build Automatically" feature and Build manually.

Thanks./

---

In response to the comment received from @Pace. I can actually check the progress and it is building other projects too. Check screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Eclipse should only be building the project that was modified when you save a file.  Furthermore, the Eclipse Java compiler handles incremental compilation so it should only build that one class file.  What leads you to suspect it is building the other projects?

Comment: check the edited part.

Comment: The Maven project builder should be doing an incremental build under the hood.  If you find it's taking a long time you might have the problem described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564872/maven-project-builder-is-invoked-every-time-i-change-a-source-file-gwt)

Answer (score 0):

You could generate jar's from the other projects, and just depend on them. That should stop it from building the other projects. You'd just have to regenerate the jar's when you change something.

Comment: Helpful, but that would require extra effort to create jar and adding it to workspace.

Comment: It'd only be a little effort to create an Ant task to handle that for you.