# Eclipse keeps building workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, coldfusion, cfeclipse

I'm using Eclipse Mars 4.5.0 IDE, and developing ColdFusion applications using CFEclipse plugin. Also, I have SVN Subversion and FileSync plugins.

The company, which I work, has a huge repository. I synchronized all files to the my own workspace and when I do any changes in Eclipse it should update my own workspace and development folder in our server.

It works fine, but sometimes, let's say once a week it starts to build workspace automatically. As I said workspace is huge, so it takes forever.

I cannot do any changes while it was building. Actually I can change the codes but I cannot save the file, saving task is just waiting to build workspace. When I cancel the building task, then try to save the code, before saving building workspace start again.

It's really annoying. I cannot do any work, I have to leave my computer at the work, when I came next morning building is done, and I can start to work. I tried everything to get ride of it, none of them worked.

Also project build automatically is unchecked. But when I do chances in the code, I have to build project not the workspace to sync the code to the development. But of course it builds all workspace not just project.

Interesting thing is that it is not happening all the time. Sometime it works fine, sometime not. For example, yesterday, I just copied one folder from one project to another one, and tried to build project, but Eclipse build whole workspace. I don't know what to do?

**EDIT:** Screenshot is added.

[image]

Comment: Please make the explanation more concise. Screenshots may also be helpful.

Comment: @DizzyCode Screenshot is added.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried unchecking build automatically in 
Window/preferences/general/workspace?

**EDIT:**
similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724109/eclipse-build-automatically-for-specific-project-currently-open-in-workspace) has been asked before on SO.
The answer was (as far as I can understand) to make jar-s out of projects that you use but don't want to compile them every time.

Comment: That would be extra effort to create jar adding it to workspace

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have unchecked the option Build Automatically under the Project menu.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I already unchecked the option Build Automatically