# How do I run a maven/eclipse/GWT/playN app in production mode?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven, playn

There seems to be an issue if you want to launch a playN/GWT/maven app from eclipse in production mode using the following procedure:

1. Right click on playn-showcase-html and select Goolge-GWT Compile

   `Compiling module playn.showcase.Showcase
      Resolving com.google.gwt.validation.client.constraints.AbstractDecimalMaxValidator
         Found type 'com.google.gwt.validation.client.constraints.AbstractDecimalMaxValidator'
            Found type 'javax.validation.constraints.DecimalMax'
               [WARN] Detected warnings related to 'javax.validation.Constraint'.   Is validation-<version>.jar on the classpath?
               Specify -logLevel DEBUG to see all errors.
               [WARN] Ignoring unresolvable annotation type javax.validation.Constraint
      Compiling 1 permutation
         Compiling permutation 0...
      Compile of permutations succeeded
   Linking into /Users/bryan/dev/playn-samples/showcase/html/target/playn-showcase-html-1.0-SNAPSHOT/showcase
      Link succeeded
      Compilation succeeded -- 19.459s`

   Anyone know what these warnings are about?
2. Right click on playn-showcase-html and select Run As web application
3. Go to URL http://127.0.0.1:8888/Showcase.html in your browser and you'll get an error that says `GWT module 'showcase' may need to be (re)compiled`.

The only way around this appears to be if you swap steps 1 & 2, but that just seems backwards.  I think the problem is that the when you run the web app from eclipse that the gwt maven plugin is compiling/deploying the artifacts again which step on your previous GWT compile step.

Anyways, this isn't a huge deal since you can reverse the order of steps to get it to work, but I was just curious if anyone has found a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try to compile/run it with maven directly, not through Eclipse, first go to  the root directory of your game and do the following:

`mvn clean package`

that should compile your game without problems, and then

`mvn test -Ptest-html`

and that should run your game in http://localhost:8080/

Hope this helps, and I strongly suggest that use maven directly whenever you can, because Eclipse has a lot of incompatibility problems with some things.

Comment: Ya, unfortunately that doesn't work for our dev/work cycle.  That really takes more time then just running it from eclipse with the workaround.

Comment: Maybe you could try to use the maven goals directly from Eclipse, I use Netbeans, but Eclipse should have the same options, maybe this could help you a little http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632425/howto-start-maven-compile-goal-on-save-in-eclipse